# JavaScript: Code to capture System time by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need a javascript code that would help me create a button and when click on the button it would start to capture the system time.

Once the time capture starts two additional buttons should reflect Pause and Stop. When i click on pause button the time capture should stop. Again if i click on the pause (which changes to start) button the time should start to capture again. When i click on stop the time capture should stop totally and the buttons deactivate.

The time capture should be in minutes.

Here is what i have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert("Hello World!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </body>

</html>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getTimeStamp() {
        var now = new Date();
        return ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? (
           "0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes()));
    }
</script>
<p><input type="button" value="Start Time" onClick="getTimeStamp();"></p>
```

Comment: People here are not doing the whole code for you, sorry.

Comment: Why dont you try first and show us what you have achieved.

Comment: How much money do I get?

Comment: I dont understand the need to make repetitive comments of a similar nature on this question. It is pretty easily understood that the OP has not tried anything or else he would state so. So stop giving this question unnecessary attention and lets come back to this when he makes a substantial edit

Comment: this is what i have tried so far.

Comment: which is not even related to your question, it's just a hello world example....

Comment: @RenatoLyke, please post that code in your question itself, not in comments.

Comment: @RenatoLyke please click on edit to add these things directly to your question

Comment: I tried implementing this code in the above code. Still when i click on the button i dont get the start time

Comment: @RenatoLyke, I have posted an incomplete solution for you. please look at it

Comment: I would like nobody to downvote me for trying please. I know i am trying to spoon feed Renato here but sometimes "its hard to start when you dont know where the starting line is".

Comment: Hi i understand how the code works. The problem is my knowledge is limited in writing an advanced code. Because of my understanding how the code needs to work. I tried the above two steps. First to see when i click on a button whether hello world will pop up or not. The second code is to see whether i can get the time. So would request you not to keep this question on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an imcomplete solution to your problem. I will complete it soon as but I would like you to try and complete it.

[Incomplete Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/wru7M/1/)

***Javascript***

```
  function myFunction() {
      var btnstop = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      var btnplaypause = document.createElement("BUTTON");
      var t = document.createTextNode("Stop");
      var u = document.createTextNode("Pause");
      btnstop.appendChild(t);
      btnplaypause.appendChild(u);
      my_button = document.getElementById("wrapper");
      my_button.appendChild(btnstop);
      my_button.appendChild(btnplaypause);
      btnstop.id = "stop";
      btnplaypause.id = "playpause"
      btnstop.onclick = stoptimer;
      startTime();
  }

  function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
      }
      return i;
  }

  function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      // add a zero in front of numbers<10
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      t = setTimeout(function () {
          startTime()
      }, 500);
  }

  function stoptimer() {
      document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("playpause").disabled = true;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks i am trying to complete the same. I am New to JS. Never worked on JS earlier. A task i have been given trying to accomplish it.